# Add layout over Google map fragment

Tags: java, android, xml

I have 'RelativeLayout' and GoogleMap fragment.

Why when I add layout over GoogleMap fragment, I still can navigate on map (I can't tap on layout)?

Here is my

[image: xml file]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your layout `clickable` `android:clickable="true"`

Comment: Oh, I am so inattentive. Than you very much!